# Jquery unlimited number array event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if this is even what you call it, but basically, I am grabbing a list of cities that is stored in one key in local storage. I am splitting them by comma, and then dynamically checking the checkboxes with the corresponding values for the id. Now I want to have any number of cities in there so I don't want to check the boxes individually like [0], [1] etc but is there there like a unlimited way to do this or something. Sorry if this isn't clear..Ill post my code below, My code below is checking the boxes from keys 0-5, I want to be  able to do 0 - unlimited , so to speak. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var refreshId = setInterval(function()
                                        {
            var citySplit = localStorage.getItem("city2");

            var myResult = citySplit.split(",");

            $("#"+myResult[0]+"").prop("checked", true);
            $("#"+myResult[1]+"").prop("checked", true);
            $("#"+myResult[2]+"").prop("checked", true);
            $("#"+myResult[3]+"").prop("checked", true);
            $("#"+myResult[4]+"").prop("checked", true);
            $("#"+myResult[5]+"").prop("checked", true);
             }, 6500);

            </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Many ways to do this:

**NOTE:** All of these examples are untested.

---

Simple `while`-loop - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

```
var i = 0,
    len = myResult.length;

while ( i < len ) {
    $( "#" + myResult[i] ).prop("checked", true);
    i++;
}
```

---

Simple `for`-loop - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

```
for ( var i = 0, len = myResult.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    $( "#" + myResult[i] ).prop("checked", true);
}
```

---

`jQuery.each` method with callback using `this`

```
$.each(myResult, function() {
    $( "#" + this ).prop("checked", true);
}
```

or
`jQuery.each` method with callback using `arguments[1]` (`value`)

```
$.each(myResult, function(key, value) {
    $( "#" + value ).prop("checked", true);
}
```

---

`while`-loop from behind 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

```
var len = myResult.length

while( len-- ) {
    $( "#" + myResult[len] ).prop("checked", true);
}
```

---

`for`-loop from behind 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

```
for( var i = myResult.length; i > 0; i-- )
    $( "#" + myResult[i-1] ).prop("checked", true);
```

---

`while`-loop popping array This destroys the array from behind 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

```
while( myResult.length ) {
    $( "#" + myResult.pop() ).prop("checked", true);
}
```

or
`while`-loop shifting array This destroys the array from the start 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

```
while( myResult.length ) {
    $( "#" + myResult.shift() ).prop("checked", true);
}
```

---

???

---

```
$.map(myResult, function(value) {
    return "#" + value;
}).each(function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
};
```

---

```
$.map(myResult, function( value ) {
    return $("#" + value);
}).prop("checked", true);
```

---

As you can see there is many ways to dealing with arrays.

For simple thing I will recommend you to use one of the two first methods.

The `jQuery.each` method is very nice because you get a the key and value of the array in a local scope. (key = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...) (value = what ever `myResult[key]` is).

The two where we destroy the array is also very nice. But I will not recommend you **not** to use these before you understand more simple methods. As situation i can think of using this method is if you have to load a lot of files or initialize a lot of functions in a specific order:

```
var func1 = function() {
        alert("func1");
    },
    func2 = function() {
        alert("func2");
    },
    func3 = function() {
        alert("func3");
    },
    queue = [func1, func2, func3];

while( queue.length ) {
    (queue.shift())(); 
    // or
    //(queue.pop())();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over `myResult`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < myResult.length; i++) {
     $("#"+myResult[i]+"").prop("checked", true);
}
```

Comment: Why do you append **empty** string in the end of the selector?

Comment: saving .length before the for loop would be more optimal IMHO

Comment: @gdoron, I just copied his checkbox manipulations.  You are correct about the empty string on the end.

Comment: @hvgotcodes I have not profiled such changes personally, but I found this viewpoint in an expert's article here : http://www.sitepoint.com/google-closure-how-not-to-write-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Add a class name to the common checkboxes and let jQuery do the work all in one go.

```
$(".myChecks").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use length of the city array.

```
 var myResult = citySplit.split(",");
 var upto = myResult.length;
 for(var i =0;i< upto ; i++)
       $("#"+myResult[i]+"").prop("checked", true);
```